# бот переводчик в телеграмм (запрос текста от пользователя)

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, перевод

Я пишу бота для перевода с Английского языка на русский, для этого нашёл хорошую библиотеку translate, поскольку google по каким-то причинам отказывается работать.
во время создания такого бота я столкнулся с проблемой. мне нужно: после нажатия кнопки на клавиатуре, бот должен запросить текст у пользователя, и прислать ему его перевод

```
elif message.text == 'Перевод':
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи мне текст на Английском языке')
    # тут он должен запрашивать текст у пользователя
    translator = Translator(to_lang="Russian")
    translation = translator.translate('тут по идее можно сделать переменную с текстом от пользователя')
    #тут он должен выводить уже переведённый текст
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, translation)
```

Answer (score 0):

В такой ситуации можно воспользоваться абстракцией Finite-state machine.
Короче говоря после просьбы ввести английский текст условие будет завершено, а пользователю, который должен прислать текст, нужно присвоить состояние ожидания текста, и при последующих сообщениях проверять пользователя на наличие такого состояние. 
В некоторых бот-фреймворках из коробки присутствует FSM, поэтому стоит почитать документацию к используемой вами телеграм библиотеке, возможно там уже есть данный функционал.

Также можно создать обычный список, в котором хранить нужных пользователей.

```
users = [] #список с пользователями, от которых ожидается ответ
if message.chat.id in users:
    users.remove(message.chat.id)
    translator = Translator(to_lang="Russian")
    translation = translator.translate(message.text)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, translation)

elif message.text == 'Перевод':
    users.append(message.chat.id)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Введи мне текст на Английском языке')
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное!)